# Is there any existing mathematical theory or problem or framework to represent the sequence of repeated numbers in the elliptical format?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to understand how to represent this sequence of numbers in an elliptical format.

Here's my mental model of the problem

Let's take this sequence of numbers

68.1,68.1,68.1,68.2,68.2,68.2,68.2,68.1,68.3,68.3,68.2,68.3,68.3,68.3,68.3,68.1,68.1,68.1,68.0,68.0,68.0,67.9,68.0,68.0,67.8,67.9,68.1,68.2,68.2,68.3,68.5,68.4,68.4,68.3,68.3,68.2,68.2,68.2,68.1,68.1,68.3,68.4,68.6,68.6,68.6,68.6,68.6,68.5,68.5,68.5,68.5,68.5,68.3,68.1,68.2,68.2,68.1,67.9,67.9,67.7,67.7,67.6,67.4,67.6,67.4,67.5,67.5,67.5,67.6,67.4,67.4,67.5,67.5,67.5,67.6,67.8,67.6,67.6,67.6,67.6,67.7,67.8,67.7,67.8,67.8,67.7,67.7,67.6,67.5,67.7,67.6,67.7,67.6,67.7,67.7,67.8,67.8,67.8,67.9,67.7,67.7,67.8,67.7,67.9,67.8,67.8,67.8,67.9,67.9,67.9,67.9,67.9,67.8,67.9,68.0,68.0,67.9,67.9,68.0,68.0,68.0,68.0,68.0,68.1,68.1,68.1,68.1,68.0,68.0,68.1,68.5,68.4,68.3

As you can see in the above sequence, certain numbers are repeating multiple times and some may not.  what i would like to draw is a series of elliptical circles with plotted numbers on the curve and the center /focal points could be 0.25%, 0.5%, 0.75%, 1% from the center value.

So, i am looking to understand how to generate an elliptical representation with  center / f1 / f2 values of an ellipse from these numbers.

Comment: Are you asking how to draw the ellipses in a plot analogous to a ["box plot"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot), using ellipses instead of boxes?

Comment: Yes, very similar. In the case of box plot there will be a single box plot for the entire sequence. In the model i propose, there can be multiple ellipse's based on the center's value.